# Adding text to MaskedTextBox programmatically.

Tags: c#

I have a masked textbox with the Mask: 0000 applied to it.

The problem I'm having is, when I'm trying to AppendText to the TextBox, the whole mask get's filled, as opposed to just the first mask value.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: not very clear. show the code, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using "####" instead, which will only show numbers that are passed to it.

The "0000" will always show a value for every digit, and if none there, show the zero.